# How to compare substrings on python? (DNA suquencing)

Tags: python

I have an assignment in python where I have to check a pair of DNA sequence. (In this case 3 pairs)

Pair 1 (GAAGGTCGAA,
CCTCGGGA)
pair 2( ATGATGGAC,
GTGATAAGGACCC)
pair 3 (AAATTT,
GGGCCC)

check each pair to see if they have a common sequence.

Longest Common Sequences

Pair 1: TCG

Pair 2: TGAT
GGAC

Pair 3: No Common Sequence Found

I am able to get the substrings, I'm simply having difficulties comparing them and then actually printing when I do find the common sequences.

Thanks in advance.

My code so far where the txt file has the pairs I mentioned

import string
  def main():

```
# open file for reading
in_file = open ("./dna.txt", "r")

# read number of pairs
num_pairs = in_file.readline()
num_pairs = num_pairs.strip()
num_pairs = int(num_pairs)

# read pairs of dna strands
for i in range (num_pairs):
  st1 = in_file.readline()
  st2 = in_file.readline()

  st1 = st1.strip()
  st2 = st2.strip()
  print(st2, st1)
  # order strands by size
  if ( len(st1) > len(st2) ):
   dna1 = st1
   dna2 = st2
  else:
    dna1 = st2
    dna2 = st1
```

main()

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: No code, no effort shown, no help given - it's that simple

Comment: Why do you think that we should directly provide you with the correct answer? Show us your efforts before..

Answer (score 1):

An imperfect answer:

```
pair1 = ('GAAGGTCGAA', 'CCTCGGGA')
pair2 = ('ATGATGGAC', 'GTGATAAGGACCC')
pair3 = ('AAATTT', 'GGGCCC')

def findSequences(pair):
   seq1, seq2 = pair
   seqFragments = [seq1[i:i+3] for i in xrange(len(seq1)-2)]
   return [seqFragment for seqFragment in seqFragments if seqFragment in seq2]

>>> findSequences(pair1)
['TCG']

>>> findSequences(pair2)
['TGA', 'GAT', 'GGA', 'GAC']

>>> findSequences(pair3)
[]
```

The flaw is that it's only looking for 3-in-a-row sequence.

Comment: thanks for the help. 

The thing is that when grading it, they will use random pairs. The pairs I provided were merely an example.